# How to randomise the order of 3 divs showing consistently in 10sec,20sec,30sec

Tags: javascript

I have a working code with 3 divs with pics showing consistently in time 10sec,20sec,30sec.
Code is working fine but I need somehow to randomise the order so NOT always pic1 is shown in time 10sec ,pic2 is shown intime 20 sec and pic3 is shown in time 30sec. I want to randomise the order of the pics so every time page is load, pics to have different order. For example pic2 can be shown first in time 10sec, than becomes pic3 in time 20sec, than becomes pic1 in time 30 sec. And I need help with that. Here is my code:

```html
<div id="wait10sec" style="visibility: hidden">
<img src="pic1.png">  
</div>

<div id="wait20sec" style="visibility: hidden">
<img src="pic2.png">  
</div>

<div id="wait30sec" style="visibility: hidden">
<img src="pic3.png">  
</div>


<script>
function showIt() {
  document.getElementById("wait10sec").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 10000);
</script>


<script>
function showIt() {
  document.getElementById("wait20sec").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 20000);
</script>


<script>
function showIt() {
  document.getElementById("wait30sec").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 30000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's change your code to work with an shuffled array of ids `[pic1, pic2, pic3]` and change the HTML accordingly.

```js
shuffle(['pic1', 'pic2', 'pic3']).forEach((id, index) => {
  setTimeout(_ => {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
  }, (index + 1) * 10000);
});


function shuffle(arr) {
  if(!arr.length) return [];
  const index = 0|(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return [
    arr[index],
    ...shuffle([...arr.splice(0, index), ...arr.splice(1)])
  ];
}
```

```html
<div id="pic1" style="visibility: hidden">
  <img src="pic1.png">
</div>

<div id="pic2" style="visibility: hidden">
  <img src="pic2.png">
</div>

<div id="pic3" style="visibility: hidden">
  <img src="pic3.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I try this code and is working 100% fine. Thank you Sir

Answer (score -1):

You can use `div id` randomly inside `showIt()` function in each interval. A simple workaround could be:

```
<script>
var ran_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
var my10secElem = "wait" + (ran_num++ % 3 + 1) + "0sec";
var my20secElem = "wait" + (ran_num++ % 3 + 1) + "0sec";
var my0secElem = "wait" + (ran_num++ % 3 + 1) + "0sec";

function showIt() {
  document.getElementById(my10secElem).style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 10000);

function showIt2() {
  document.getElementById(my20secElem).style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt2()", 20000);

function showIt3() {
  document.getElementById(my30secElem).style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt3()", 30000);
</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(showIt, 10000)` is more idiomatic. Using strings in `setTimeout` is almost as bad as `eval`.

Comment: also should improve it with, selecting elements which have a class like `wait-show`, then using recursion timer, loop over them, incrementing 10 seconds to the timer each time.. repeating code like this is also as bad as using eval